# Android Studio can't find the native (C++) library for my project

Tags: java, android, c++, dlopen

I am just getting started with porting a library to Android, and created a basic application to test out the progress. It builds fine, however when I run it, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception saying it can't find `libnvddemo.so` (The library for my application, not the one I'm porting). This is what my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
set(SOURCES native-lib.cpp)

project("nvddemo")
add_library(
        nvddemo
        SHARED
        ${SOURCES})
find_library(
        log-lib
        log)

target_link_libraries(
        nvddemo
        ${log-lib})
```

And this is how I load my library:

```java
try {
    System.loadLibrary("nvddemo");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    Log.e("nvddemo", "Cannot link to native C++ library: " + e.toString());
    throw new RuntimeException("This project requires its C++ library to be available.");
}
```

Comment: Posting verbose build output might help, also build.gradle. There are a few ways things could fail like you describe (arch mismatch, stale CMakeLists.txt, bad build config.)

Comment: Which build.gradle of the two?

Comment: If there are two both are probably relevant